# Sharepoint 365 Client Root Element is Missing

Tags: .net-core, sharepoint, azure-functions

I have an azure function app which is triggered by files entering a storage container.  The function app does some basic metadata tagging of the file and then uploads them to our share point 365 instance.  All the files placed in the storage container are pdf files.

This has been working in production for a fairly long time now (year+), however it recently starting failing on some files.  I'm able to run the function app locally connected to our production storage container.  Inspecting the variable in the debugger I can't see anything obviously wrong.

I've followed a few solutions I've seen elsewhere, which suggest that I need to change my DNS settings, however that didn't solve the issue.  I also don't think a DNS resolution problem would explain why the function app works for some files but not other.  My strong suspicion is that there is an issue with the sharepoint instance, but I don't have access to it so can't investigate it directly.

This is the function app code:

```
[Function("UploadDocument")]
public void Run([BlobTrigger("documents/{fileName}", Connection = "ConnectionStr")] byte[] fileAsBytes, string fileName, IDictionary<string, string> metadata)
{
    var stream = new MemoryStream();
    stream.Write(fileAsBytes, 0, fileAsBytes.Length);
    var fileData = new FileData(fileName, stream);

    using (var context = new ClientContext(Settings.SiteUrl))
    {
        context.Credentials = GetCredentialsFromConfig();

        List documentLibrary = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(Settings.DocumentLibTitle);

        FileCreationInformation file = new FileCreationInformation
        {
            Content = ReadStream(fileData.GetStreamToWrite()),
            Url = fileData.FileName,
            Overwrite = true
        };

        // Add file and meta data
        Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File uploadFile = documentLibrary.RootFolder.Files.Add(file);
        file.ListItemAllFields["referenceNo"] = GetRefForFile(fileName);
        file.ListItemAllFields["Library"] = "Inc";
        file.ListItemAllFields.Update();
        uploadFile.Update();

        context.Load(documentLibrary);
        context.Load(uploadFile);

        try
        {
            context.ExecuteQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.LogError($"{ex.Message}", ex);
        }
    }
```

The exception I'm getting is:

```
"Root element is missing."
 System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception e)   
 System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseDocumentContent()   
 System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Load(XmlReader reader, LoadOptions options)   
 Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Idcrl.IdcrlAuth.DoGet(String url)   
 Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Idcrl.IdcrlAuth.RequestFederationProviderInfo(String domainname)   
 Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Idcrl.IdcrlAuth.GetFederationProviderInfo(String domainname)   
 Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Idcrl.IdcrlAuth.InitFederationProviderInfoForUser(String username)   
 Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Idcrl.IdcrlAuth.GetServiceToken(String username, String password, String serviceTarget, String servicePolicy)   
 Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Idcrl.SharePointOnlineAuthenticationProvider.GetAuthenticationCookie(Uri url, String username, SecureString password, Boolean alwaysThrowOnFailure, EventHandler`1 executingWebRequest)   
 Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials.GetAuthenticationCookie(Uri url, Boolean refresh, Boolean alwaysThrowOnFailure)   
 Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRuntimeContext.SetupRequestCredential(ClientRuntimeContext context, HttpWebRequest request)   
 Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SPWebRequestExecutor.GetRequestStream()   
 Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext.GetWebRequestExecutor()   
 Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext.GetFormDigestInfoPrivate()   
 Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext.EnsureFormDigest()   
 Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext.ExecuteQuery()   
 Program.Run(byte[] fileAsBytes, string fileName, IDictionary<string, string> metadata)
```

I'm using .net core 6.0, Microsoft.SharePoint.Client 14.0.4762.1000, and Microsoft.SharePointOnline.CSOM 16.1.24308.12000, against a Sharepoint 365 instance